# Can't find anything wrong with my algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to solve [this](http://www.codechef.com/SEP12/problems/CROWD) problem in Codechef. Now according to question, if there are 10 houses, he can make a mistake by choosing either 3 consecutive houses, or 4, or 5, ... or 10. Now the number of ways to choose `m` consecutive houses from `n` houses is `n-m+1`. So I must take a summation of `n-m+1` with `m` starting from 3 upto `n`. That is, I am adding numbers from `n-2`, `n-1` upto 1. That being in an AP, the value should be `((n-2)(n-1))/2` (by the formula `n(n+1)/2`). This is what this code does. However I am getting a wrong answer message. Where am I erring? The `pow` is for doing modular exponentiation, so that the number doesn't get out of bound at any stage.

```
testcase = int(raw_input())
m = 10**9 + 7
for i in xrange(0,testcase):
    n = int(raw_input())
    ans = ((pow(n,2,m)-3*n+2)/2)%m
    print ans
```

Comment: This is a running contest .. It would be unfair to others if u are answered .

Comment: Yeah, that's why I am not submitting this one. Some time ago I asked another similar question in this forum, and even though I got a working answer, I didn't submit it.

Comment: did you test it with small numbers and calculated the expected result by hand? maybe one of the test cases is lower than 3 and you return a negative

Comment: If my logic is correct then the algo is correct as well. It's pretty simple.

Answer (score 2):

Do you also count, say, this case?

```
( * * * * * * * * * * )
  ^ ^ ^   ^ ^ ^
```

It's just an example which I believe you skipped. (If I did follow your algorithm correctly)

It's just a hint though asking running contest problems is not OK at all.

Comment: O, so you are saying that there may be more tan one way of choosing 3+ consecutive houses in a single selection. Right.

Comment: you could also choose any other combination in the remaining houses. for 5: 1,2,3,5;1,2,3,4 are both wrong, even though 5 is just a single house. what makes it more complicated is that 1,2,3,4 might be counted twice - once as a combination of 3 + leftover choices, the second time as a choice of 4 consecutive houses